# BottomSheetBehavior with GridView flicker

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview

I tried to use gridView inside bottomSheetBehavior.
I get my data asynchronize and i call to `setAdapter` just when the user click on my button. 
The problem is that i see flicker of the data. What can i do to kill this flicker?

In my onCreate:

```
    final ViewGroup gridViewContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer);
    if (gridViewContainer != null) {
    gridView = (GridView) gridViewContainer.findViewById(R.id.actionGridView);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(gridViewContainer);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                    isBottomSheetQuickActionOpen = true;
                    gridViewContainer.requestLayout();
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                    isBottomSheetQuickActionOpen = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });

public void onBottomBarIconClicked(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.right_bottom_action:
            if (bottomSheetBehavior != null) {
                if (!isBottomSheetQuickActionOpen) {
                    setActionsForQuickDialog();
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                } else {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void setupQuickActionDialog() {
    ActionsManager actionManager = ActionsManager.get();
    List<WidgetMetaData> list = getMyList();
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list)) {
        if (gridView != null) {
            adapterGridView = new AdapterGridView(ContactDetailsActivity.this, list, contact);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapterGridView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that way:
1. Save member of runnable

```
    private final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                if (!isBottomSheetQuickActionOpen) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                } else {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                }
        }
    };
```

2. Save the main thread:

   Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
3. When button clicked, first create the gridview icons, second use the mainthread to post runnable. If we want to collapse the `bottomsheetbehaviour` we should remove the runnable from the queue and then just collapse by

   setBottomSheetState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

The function that changed:

```
public void onBottomBarIconClicked(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.open_menu_btn:
            if (bottomSheetBehavior != null) {
                if (!isBottomSheetQuickActionOpen) {
                    setActionsForQuickDialog();
                    mainHandler.post(runnable);
                } else {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    collapseBottomSheet();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```